# Where is my custom object stored when saved to settings. I can't see the data in the settings file

Tags: c#, winforms, settings

I have a person class...

```
public class Person
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }
}
```

And a PersonList class...

```
public class PersonList
{
    public List<Person> lp = new List<Person>();

    public void AddPerson(Person p)
    {
        lp.Add(p);
    }
}
```

Code to add some 'People' and save to my Project settings...

```
PersonList pl = new PersonList();
pl.AddPerson(new Person() { name = "bob", age = 25 });
pl.AddPerson(new Person() { name = "tom", age = 35 });
pl.AddPerson(new Person() { name = "bill", age = 55 });

Properties.Settings.Default.PersonList = pl;
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

I then use the following code to display the data in a datagridview... which displays as expected.

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = Properties.Settings.Default.PersonList.lp;
```

[image]

So the setting are being stored correctly but I can't find where exactly.
If i edit the setting file I get the following...

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<SettingsFile xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2004/01/settings" CurrentProfile="(Default)" GeneratedClassNamespace="Setting_File_change_location.Properties" GeneratedClassName="Settings">
  <Profiles />
  <Settings>
    <Setting Name="PersonList" Type="Data.PersonList" Scope="User">
      <Value Profile="(Default)" />
    </Setting>
  </Settings>
</SettingsFile>
```

I can see it has stored a PersonList but I can't see the 'People' is this data stored in some other file?

Answer (score 1):

The settings are stored in

```
C:\Users\[your_username]\AppData\Local\[your_appname]\[version]
```

inside a `user.config` file

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the `user.config` associated with your application.

This is normally in the `AppData` folder of the current Windows user profile.

To get the exact path you need, you can call `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)` somewhere in your code to get the value you need.